# Pandas assign values within group in cumulative order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like

[image]

The required output is:

[image]

where b0,D are just strings.. They are a part of equation which I will later evauluate.

I am having trouble in writing the code to design an logic like this.

Here's what I have in mind:

1. For each group, create a list of all the page_names
2. For each group and list we run a loop and use the lists index to calculate the values across each row

I am not sure if this will work or if there's a better way to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC try iterating over a reversed [`expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html#pandas-dataframe-expanding) window:

```
prefix = 'D'
multiplier = 'b0'
for win in df.loc[::-1, 'page_nam'].groupby(df['group']).expanding():
    t = '*'.join(prefix + win.iloc[1:])
    df.loc[win.index[-1], 'formula'] = (
        f"{t}*{multiplier}+{t}*{win.iloc[-1]}"
        if t else
        f"{multiplier}*{win.iloc[-1]}"
    )
```

`df.to_string(index=False)`:

```
group page_nam  page_num                                                                                      formula
    a    page1         1 Dpage6*Dpage5*Dpage4*Dpage3*Dpage2*Dpage1*b0+Dpage6*Dpage5*Dpage4*Dpage3*Dpage2*Dpage1*page1
    a    page2         2               Dpage6*Dpage5*Dpage4*Dpage3*Dpage2*b0+Dpage6*Dpage5*Dpage4*Dpage3*Dpage2*page2
    a    page3         3                             Dpage6*Dpage5*Dpage4*Dpage3*b0+Dpage6*Dpage5*Dpage4*Dpage3*page3
    a    page4         4                                           Dpage6*Dpage5*Dpage4*b0+Dpage6*Dpage5*Dpage4*page4
    a    page5         5                                                         Dpage6*Dpage5*b0+Dpage6*Dpage5*page5
    a    page6         6                                                                       Dpage6*b0+Dpage6*page6
    a    page7         7                                                                                     b0*page7
    b    page1         1                                                         Dpage2*Dpage1*b0+Dpage2*Dpage1*page1
    b    page2         2                                                                       Dpage2*b0+Dpage2*page2
    b    page3         3                                                                                     b0*page3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This was extremely helpful and super quick
The only change will be:
in the last value for each group (the one with max page_num) it will jsut be b0+pagename
We don't have to include the 'D' formula

Comment: I had already noticed the issue. See the update. =)

Comment: Your code is super efficient man. Ran for 1m records quickly :)
just a last request/support would be :
the last row is correct now but the ones before that should not have any isntance of D multiplied by the last page:
eg: for group b and page_num2 the formula is : Dpage2*b0+Dpage2*page2
similarly for page1 it'll be Dpage2*Dpage1*b0 + Dpage2*Dpage1*page1

Comment: Easy fix, I misunderstood which way to slice. Try now. @AkshatShreemali

Comment: I couldn't appreciate this more.. Thanks a lot Man :)